# C++ vector confusion with .size() result

Tags: c++, vector, size

With the code below, I cannot figure out why `numbs[numbs.size()]` doesn't give me an appropriate response. I would assume it would give me the last item in the sorted vector, in this case it should be the largest. Yet, `cout << numbs[numbs.size()]`spits out garbage, e.g.

> Number 1 entered. [1], smallest: 1. there are 1 elements in the vector. **1.36617e-231 is the largest.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double number_input = 0.0;
string unit = " ";

vector<double> numbs;
while (cin >> number_input)
{
    numbs.push_back(number_input);
    cout << "Number " << number_input << "entered.\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < numbs.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "[" << numbs[i] << "],";
    }

    sort(numbs.begin(),numbs.end());
    cout << "smallest: " << numbs[0] << endl;
    cout << "there are " << numbs.size() << " elements in the vector.\n";
    cout << numbs[numbs.size()] << " is the largest.";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indices are 0-based, use `numbs[numbs.size() - 1]`.

Comment: Array types and vectors are 0 indexed, meaning that the first item is item number 0, and the Nth item is item number N-1, hence why you need to use numbs[numbs.size() - 1].

Comment: Hint: What does `cout << numbs.at(0)` do?  How about `numbs.at(numbs.size())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes in a vector are 0-based, just as arrays are. So the last value in a vector `v` is `v[ v.size() - 1 ]` assuming `v.size() > 0`